# Fingerprint gui not installing in ubuntu 20.04 Even tried adding ppa

Tags: dell, 20.04, policykit

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

but I got the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package policykit-1-fingerprint-gui
E: Unable to locate package fingerprint-gui
```

Please help quickly to get rid of it and work with my fingerprint sensor — Synaptics VFS7552.

[image]

Comment: please give answer to this question